# 'str' object is not callable in my cycling

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1, 27):
    temp=str(i)
    print '%s'(temp.zfill(3))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I wonder why？

for I want the output to like this :

```
001
002
```

..

```
021
```

...

so I use `zfill`.
But python tell me it is "`str` object is not callable"
how to solve it?

Comment: By the way, you could simply `print '%03d' % i` and avoid `temp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `%` in

```
print '%s' % (temp.zfill(3))
           ^ THIS
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print '%s'(temp.zfill(3))
```

should be

```
print '%s' % temp.zfill(3)
```

actually there is no need for `%s`
you can just use

```
print temp.zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jamylak and @NPE indicated you forgot the `%` operator and you actually do not need it.

However if you want to do string formatting you should consider using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) as it is preferred over using `%`:

```
for i in range(1, 27):
    print '{0:0{1}}'.format(i, 3)
```